# Problem filtering NSArrayController

Tags: objective-c, filter, nspredicate, nsarraycontroller

I have problem filtering an NSArrayController. Content Array is bound to an NSMutableArray holding NSDictionaries. I want to filter all NSDictionaries whose "name" key equals "a".
I run these two lines when my app launches but nothing gets filtered.

```
NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"name like %@", @"a"];

[arrayController setFilterPredicate: filter];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"name=%@", @"a"];

[arrayController setFilterPredicate: filter];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(name contains[cd] $a)"];
[arrayController setFilterPredicate: filter];
```